# Sheetname in combo box userform

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm looking for a way to add the sheetnames to my combobox.

Final result should be:

2 combo boxes next to each other were in the first box I can enter the sheetname and with the second box data from the sheet I just selected.

I'm making creating an inventory and my goal is to create a userfrom in wich I can edit my data more easily. I got about 10 sheets with the names of manufactures as sheet name. Now I would like to create a combo box in wich I can enter the sheetname and that it would give me in my second combo box some data from the sheet.

The second box is not important right now. I just would like to select my sheets in the first box.

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Again, I'm making creating a inventory and my goal is to create a userfrom in wich I can edit my data more easily. I got about 10 sheets with the names of manufactures as sheet name. Now I would like to create a combo box in wich I can enter the sheetname and that it would give me in my second combo box some data from the sheet. The second box is not important right now I just would like to select my sheets in the first box.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with VBA, here is an answer on [SO] - [VBA Excel Drop-down List for Worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602394/1141581).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oCmbBox As MSForms.ComboBox

    Set oCmbBox = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).cmbSheet

    oCmbBox.Clear

    For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        oCmbBox.AddItem oSheet.Name

    Next oSheet

End Sub
```

I tried it in Excel 2010 and it worked for me. There is more to it than that if you want to modify things yourself.